# Failed to start load kernel modules after install virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch-linux, kernel

've installed virtual box few days ago, and I tried to load kernel modules but I got an error, so I've forced to load modules

```
sudo modprobe --force vboxdrv
```

and since then, everytime when I boot my laptop it says

```
Failed to start Load Kernel Modules
```

And while doing system maintenance, and checking for errors using

```
systemctl --failed
```

Here is the output:

```
 UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                
 ● systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed Load Kernel     Modules        

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of  SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed.
```

and output of:

```
journalctl -p 3 -xb
```

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-07-11 14:02:07 EET, end at Sun 2019-09-08 13:03:06 EET. --
Sep 08 12:13:33 D-Link systemd-fstab-generator[276]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/-.mount, as it already exists.>
Sep 08 12:13:33 D-Link systemd[270]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator failed with exit status 1.
Sep 08 12:13:36 D-Link kernel: vboxdrv: version magic '5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload ' should be '5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH SMP >
Sep 08 12:13:36 D-Link kernel: vboxdrv: version magic '5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload ' should be '5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH SMP >
Sep 08 12:13:36 D-Link kernel: vboxdrv: version magic '5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload ' should be '5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH SMP >
Sep 08 12:13:36 D-Link kernel: vboxdrv: version magic '5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload ' should be '5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH SMP >
Sep 08 12:13:34 D-Link systemd-modules-load[284]: Failed to insert module 'vboxdrv': Exec format error
Sep 08 12:13:34 D-Link systemd-modules-load[284]: Failed to insert module 'vboxpci': Exec format error
Sep 08 12:13:34 D-Link systemd-modules-load[284]: Failed to insert module 'vboxnetadp': Exec format error
Sep 08 12:13:34 D-Link systemd-modules-load[284]: Failed to insert module 'vboxnetflt': Exec format error
Sep 08 12:13:34 D-Link systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit systemd-modules-load.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 23 and the job result is failed.
Sep 08 12:13:40 D-Link systemd-modules-load[491]: Failed to insert module 'vboxdrv': Exec format error
Sep 08 12:13:40 D-Link kernel: vboxdrv: version magic '5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload ' should be '5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH SMP >
Sep 08 12:13:40 D-Link systemd-modules-load[491]: Failed to insert module 'vboxpci': Exec format error
Sep 08 12:13:40 D-Link kernel: vboxdrv: version magic '5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload ' should be '5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH SMP >
lines 1-23
Sep 08 12:13:40 D-Link systemd-modules-load[491]: Failed to insert module 'vboxnetflt': Exec format error
Sep 08 12:13:40 D-Link systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit systemd-modules-load.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 128 and the job result is failed.
Sep 08 12:13:40 D-Link kernel: vboxdrv: version magic '5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload ' should be '5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH SMPpreempt    mod_unload ' should be '5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload
```

anyone know hot solve this problem??

Comment: Try the latest version of Virtualbox (now on v6.0.12).

Comment: I don't care about virtualbox, I am just afraid that my laptop won't boot one day because of that failure, so I want to solve it, do I have to remove virtualbox for the failure to be solved?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.